# Check android runtime

Tags: android, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

Since it's now possible to execute an apk file on windows mobile, is there any way to check if the environment is emulated on windows or not? I want to be aware if the app is executed on windows platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. You just need to read file /proc/cmdline and look for the hyperv string.

Answer (score 0):

Users cannot run arbitrary APKs on Windows. As a developer you will choose to package and publish your APK for Windows. It can call Windows Runtime API or compile in custom checks as needed.

For more information check out the Build session [“PROJECT ASTORIA“: Build Great Windows Apps with Your Android Code](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-702). You can sign up for the for the Windows Bridge for Android (fka Project Astoria) developer preview at https://dev.windows.com/en-us/uwp-bridges/android